# Format number by rounding up

Tags: rust

I have a number which I want to print with a fixed precision, rounded up.  I know I can use `{:.3}` to truncate it.

```rust
assert_eq!("0.0123", format!("{:.3}", 0.0123456))
```

Is there a simple way to "ceil" it instead?

```rust
assert_eq!("0.0124", format!("{:magic}", 0.012301))
assert_eq!("0.0124", format!("{:magic}", 0.012399))
assert_eq!("0.0124", format!("{:magic}", 0.0124))
```

I can do something like

```
let x = format!("{:.3}", (((y * 1000.0).ceil() + 0.5) as i64) as f64 / 1000.0)
```

which is pretty unreadable.  It also gives me would give me 3 digits after the decimal point, not three digits of precision, so I need to figure out the scale the number, probably with something like `-log10(y) as i64`

In case it's not clear, I want a string to show the user, not an f64.

**More examples**

```rust
assert_eq!("1.24e-42", format!("{:magic}", 1.234e-42))
assert_eq!("1240", format!("{:magic}", 1234.5)) // "1240." also works
```

If the f64 representing 0.123 is slightly larger than the real number 0.123, displaying "0.124" is acceptable.

The two requirements are:

1. The string, when converted back to an f64, is greater than or equal to the original f64 (so 0.123 -> "0.124" is acceptable)
2. The string has 3 significant digits (although dropping trailing zeros is acceptable, so 0.5 -> "0.5" and "0.5 -> "0.500" both work)

In case it comes up, the input number will always be positive.

Comment: @Stargateur Looks like OP needs to round up and display a specific number of decimal places, not an integer

Comment: @PeterHall `(x * 1000).ceil() / 1000` ?

Comment: @Stargateur except that they are looking for significant figures not a fixed number of decimal places, so that `1000` value would vary based on the most significant digit in the input.

Comment: Also, if you start multiplying floats like that, you'll end up with some edge cases where it will be off by one.

Comment: @PeterHall there is no significant number information inside a f64

Comment: @Stargateur There is after you've formatted it!

Comment: The assertion in the first code example fails – `{:.3}` means formatting to three decimal places after the point, not to three significant places. Since you have very specific (and rather unusual) requirements how you want to format your number, you need to code this yourself.

Comment: Could you give a few more examples? What result do you expect for `1.234e-42` and `1234.5`?

Comment: there is a simple crate that look simple but do what you want I think https://docs.rs/pretty_dtoa/0.3.0/pretty_dtoa/struct.FmtFloatConfig.html#method.max_significant_digits

Comment: FYI, the [docs for `std::fmt`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/index.html) document the `format!` syntax, although there isn't any built-in way to dothis.

Comment: The trouble with questions like this is that it's unclear what number the rounding should apply to - the floating-point number in the memory (not equivalent to the decimal implementation such as `0.0123`), or to the original string representation (which is unavailable at run-time). To give a concrete example: what should `format!("{:magic}", 0.0123)` return? Keep in mind that the `f64` closest to `0.0123` is `7090467253332109/576460752303423488`, which is slightly greater than `123/10000`, so a round-up implementation will format it as `"0.0124"`, which I have a hunch is not desired.

Comment: @troydaniels Thanks for the clarification. What you need should be doable through a decimal library, such as [this function](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2ce1c66cfecf582fb56bf5ff0a5f4cd7) that uses [`rust_decimal`](https://crates.io/crates/rust-decimal). However there seems to be a [bug in rust_decimal](https://github.com/paupino/rust-decimal/issues/430) that prevents it from working correctly. Hopefully the maintainer will fix the issue.

Comment: It seems that the issues in `rust_decimal` have been fixed; I've updated the answer accordingly. I am curious about the use case that led to this requirement. Did you end up using the code in the answer, did you roll your own, or give up on the specific rounding strategy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is harder than it seems because there is no way to tell the formatting machinery to change the rounding strategy. Also, format precision works on the number of digits after the decimal point, not on the number of significant digits. (AFAIK there is no equivalent to the `printf("%.3g", n)`, and even if there were, it wouldn't round up.)

You can use a decimal arithmetic crate such as [`rust_decimal`](https://crates.io/crates/rust-decimal) to do the heavy-lifting - something like:

```
use rust_decimal::prelude::*;

pub fn fmtup(n: f64, ndigits: u32) -> String {
    let d = Decimal::from_f64_retain(n).unwrap();
    d.round_sf_with_strategy(ndigits, RoundingStrategy::AwayFromZero)
        .unwrap()
        .normalize()
        .to_string()
}
```

**EDIT**: The answer originally included a manual implementation of the rounding due to issues in `rust_decimal` which have since been fixed. As of Oct 24 2021 the above snippet using `rust_decimal` is the recommended solution. The only exception is if you need to handle numbers that are very large or very close to zero (such as 1.234e-42 or 1.234e42), which are approximated to zero or rejected by `rust_decimal`.

---

To manually round to significant digits, one can scale the number until it has the desired number of digits before the decimal point, and then round it up. In case of 3 digits, scaling would multiply or divide it by 10 until it falls between 100 and 1000. After rounding the number, format the resulting whole number as string, and insert the `.` at the position determined by the amount of scaling done in the first step.

To avoid inexactness of floating-point division by ten, the number can be first converted to a fraction, and then all operations can proceed on the fraction. Here is an implementation that uses the ubiquitous `num` crate to provide fractions:

```
use num::{rational::BigRational, FromPrimitive};

/// Format `n` to `ndigits` significant digits, rounding away from zero.
pub fn fmtup(n: f64, ndigits: i32) -> String {
    // Pass 0 (which we can't scale), infinities and NaN to f64::to_string()
    if n == 0.0 || !n.is_finite() {
        return n.to_string();
    }
    // Handle negative numbers the easy way.
    if n < 0.0 {
        return format!("-{}", fmtup(-n, ndigits));
    }

    // Convert the input to a fraction. From this point onward, we are only doing exact
    // arithmetic.
    let mut n = BigRational::from_float(n).unwrap();

    // Scale N so its whole part is ndigits long, meaning truncating it will result in an
    // integer ndigits long. If ndigits is 3, we'd want N to be in (100, 1000] range, so
    // that e.g. 0.012345 would be scaled to 123.45, and then rounded up to 124.
    let mut scale = 0i16;
    let ten = BigRational::from_u8(10).unwrap();
    let lower_bound = ten.pow(ndigits - 1);
    if n < lower_bound {
        while n < lower_bound {
            n *= &ten;
            scale -= 1;
        }
    } else {
        let upper_bound = lower_bound * &ten;
        while n >= upper_bound {
            n /= &ten;
            scale += 1;
        }
    }
    // Round N up
    n = n.ceil();
    // Format the number as integer and place the decimal point at the right position.
    let mut s = n.to_string();
    // multiply N with 10**scale, i.e. append zeros if SCALE is positve, otherwise
    // insert the point inside or before the number
    if scale > 0 {
        s.extend(std::iter::repeat('0').take(scale as _));
    } else if scale < 0 {
        // Find where to place the decimal point in the string.
        let point_pos = s.len() as i16 + scale;
        if point_pos <= 0 {
            // Negative position means before beginning of the string, so we have
            // to pad with zeros. E.g. s == "123" and point_pos == -2 means we
            // want "0.00123", and with point_pos == 0 we'd want "0.123".
            let mut pad = "0.".to_string();
            pad.extend(std::iter::repeat('0').take(-point_pos as _));
            pad.push_str(&s);
            s = pad;
            // Trim trailing zeros after decimal point. E.g. 0.25 gets scaled to
            // 250 and then ends up "0.250".
            s.truncate(s.trim_end_matches('0').len());
        } else {
            // Insert the decimal point in the middle of string. E.g. s == "123"
            // and point_pos == 1 would result in "1.23".
            let point_pos = point_pos as usize;
            if s.as_bytes()[point_pos..].iter().all(|&digit| digit == b'0') {
                // if only zeros are after the decimal point, e.g. "10.000", omit those
                // digits instead of placing the decimal point.
                s.truncate(point_pos);
            } else {
                s.insert(point_pos, '.');
            }
        }
    }
    s
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1fd701c9f60604368fc77c44fc0e719c)

Here are some test cases:

```
fn main() {
    let fmt3up = |n| fmtup(n, 3);

    assert_eq!("12400", fmt3up(12301.));
    assert_eq!("1240", fmt3up(1234.5));
    assert_eq!("124", fmt3up(123.01));

    assert_eq!("1000", fmt3up(1000.));
    assert_eq!("999", fmt3up(999.));
    assert_eq!("1010", fmt3up(1001.));
    assert_eq!("100", fmt3up(100.));
    assert_eq!("10", fmt3up(10.));
    assert_eq!("99", fmt3up(99.));
    assert_eq!("101", fmt3up(101.));
    assert_eq!("0.25", fmt3up(0.25));

    assert_eq!("12400", fmt3up(12301.0));
    assert_eq!("0.0124", fmt3up(0.0123)); // because 0.0123 is slightly above 123/10_000
    assert_eq!("0.0124", fmt3up(0.012301));
    assert_eq!("0.00124", fmt3up(0.0012301));
    assert_eq!("0.0124", fmt3up(0.012399));
    assert_eq!("0.0124", fmt3up(0.0124));
    assert_eq!("0.124", fmt3up(0.12301));
    assert_eq!("1.24", fmt3up(1.2301));
    assert_eq!("1.24", fmt3up(1.234));
}
```

Note that this will display `1.234e-42` as `0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000124`, but an improvement that to switch to exponential notation should be fairly straightforward.